# Height Of A Vector Respect To A SubSpace

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can anyone explain me what means the following:

To compute the volume of a $n$ dimensional parallelepiped we use the base x height rule, we pick a vector, then height is the distance from this vector to the subspace spanned by the remainimg vectors,  where base is the $(n-1)$ dimensional volume formed by the remaining vectors.

¿What means height there?, I  understand it with $2$, $3$ dimensions, but what about 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says:

> height is the distance from this vector to the subspace spanned by the remainimg vectors

If the vectors are $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$, then $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1}$ span a subspace $W$.  The distance from $v_n$ to $W$ is the minimum length of all vectors $v_n - w$, as $w$ ranges over $W$.

It's unlikely you would need to compute this height directly.  Most of the time the volume of a parallelepiped would be computed using the determinant formula.

Comment: I understand it, could you provide more details about what means that in a 4d example? Specially how relate the idea of height as a minimum distance with volumen. This is trying to understand intuition behind determinant

Comment: It doesn't mean anything different in 4d, because the measurement is of something one-dimensional.  $v_n$ has a unique component in the direction perpendicular to $W$, and $h$ is the height of that component.